# How to find all files which are basically soft or hard links of other directories or files on linux?

Tags: linux, shell, find, hardlink, symlink

How could I get the list of all linked files on my system or from a certain directory. I used to create links but they became unmanageable with time. I want the list of all such links from a directory. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think this belongs to serverfault

Comment: not serverfault... there is nothing server or network related here... it is superuser.com

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finding symlinks is easy:

```
% find . -type l
```

Finding hard links is tricky, because if a subdirectory of the directory in question also has subdirectories then those increase the hard link count.  That's how subdirectories are linked to their parents in UNIX (it's the `..` entry in each subdirectory).

If you only want to find linked *files* (and not directories), this will work:

```
% find . -type f \! -links 1
```

This works because a file that *does* have hard links will have a link count > 1, and unlinked file has a link count == 1, hence this command looks for all files whose link count <> 1

Alternatively, on newer versions of `find` you could use:

```
% find . -type f -links +1
```

This works for the same reason as above; however, newer versions of find can take +n or -n instead of just a number.  This is equivalent to testing for greater than n or less than n, respectively.

Comment: Er... can a file have <1 link? I mean, wouldn't that make it a fileless inode?

Comment: @naught101 well, supplying -1 would indeed fail to find any files.

Answer (score 3):

```
find / -xdev -samefile filename
```

Answer (score 2):

@OP, If you have GNU find, you can find hard links using `-printf "%n"`, 
e.g.

```
find /path -type f -printf "%f/%n/%i\n" | while IFS="/" read filename num_hlinks inum
do
 echo "Filename: $filename. Number of hard links: $num_hlinks, inode: $inum"
 # if 2 or more files have the same inode number, then they are hard links. 
 # you can therefore count how many $inum that are the same and determine those hard links, which 
 # you have to try doing yourself.
done
```

Answer (score 1):

See e.g. here
https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Hard-Links.html
or combine Alnitak and amber_linux answer into
`find -L /where/to/search -samefile /some/link/to/file`
to find all hard and soft links to a given file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was looking for - how to find which other files are in fact the same file as the one I'm looking at.